Laravel Filament login error on auth pages
I've just had an error said 'The POST method is not supported for route admin/login. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.' on the login and registration pages.
My project is working properly when it is local, but it is not working on my shared host.
Could anyone help me?
When I faced this issue on the login page I tried to add a registration page to check if it is works or not. But it does not work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
